# Google Console - Error: Clickable elements too close together - Affected pages: 0

Tags: google-search-console

Google's automatic mobile issue detection is telling me that my site has clickable elements that are too close and that this problem affects zero pages.

I'm assuming it's a Google bug?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely ignore it. I receive these same email warnings. There is absolutely nothing wrong with my page (I get a specific page listed in my warning). The warnings come, like in your case, irregularly, sometimes the site presents 0 errors, sometimes it is this 1 error, even though the site hasn't been changed in a few years. The whole Google webmaster tools thing has been bad quality from day one.